# when does img src doesn't work for image at outside?

Tags: html, image, src

I'm trying to use `<img src=...`  for this image http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/mobile_visualviewport.jpg

When I open up the image in browser by typing clicking the url, the image shows up.

However, when I try to show the same image by using `<img src=..url />` , the image is not found and not shown.

What causes this difference?

Comment: What exactly is the source in your second example?

Comment: it should work, just check the quotes, i think you miss the quotes

Comment: are you putting the url in quotes eg.
    <img src="http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/mobile_visualviewport.jpg">

Comment: `<img src="http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/mobile_visualviewport.jpg" />`  this should work

Comment: check it http://jsfiddle.net/Vinay199129/DvnSV/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because all the answers you are getting as non-answer "Cannot reproduce" reports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/mobile_visualviewport.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following code should be work: Please Try this,

img src="http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/mobile_visualviewport.jpg" /

P

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this http://jsfiddle.net/aMYra/

`<img src="http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/pix/viewport/mobile_visualviewport.jpg" />`